# Telegram bot. Как сделать так чтоб бот отправил текстовую ссылку, при нажатии на которую ее текст отправлялся в чат?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Уточню вопрос так:

1. Можно взаимодействовать с ботом командами, когда в сообщении от бота содержится что либо типа `/my_command`, при клике на команду, она отправляется в чат, далее идет обработка этой команды...
2. Можно добавить клавиатуру под поле ввода сообщений с кнопками, нажатие на которые отправит в чат текст на этих кнопках...
3. Можно взаимодействовать кнопками, отображаемыми сразу под сообщениями бота (*inline*)...

А как взаимодействовать с ботом гиперссылками? Может быть есть какой-то способ чтобы бот выдал в сообщении текстовую ссылку, при нажатие на которую боту отправлялся текст ссылки, или какой-либо другой текст, или команда, или параметр, или еще что-либо, что можно обработать?

Тут важен момент **одного клика**, как в примере с командами. Есть варианты? Если нет, то может быть есть еще какие-то способы взаимодействия с ботом в моменте одного клика?

**UPD:**

Если прям сильно подробно, то задача стоит такая. Бот отправляет сообщение со ссылкой. **При клике** на ссылку сразу же отправляется исходящее сообщение с командой, текстом ссылки, любым другим текстом, например так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или лучше так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или еще лучше вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или в идеале вообще "молча", без отправки исходящего сообщения (по аналогии с inline-кнопками под сообщением) сразу же отправляются какие либо параметры, которые можно забрать из Update.

Comment: А чем не устраивают кнопки? Вы же хотите функционал одного клика, пожалуйста

Comment: Вероятны вы про deep-linking. Передача параметра в ссылке: t.me/mybot?start=123456abc. А боту приходит команда /start 123456abc

Comment: @MrShandy - Мне важно отсутствие слеша, т.к. 1) не красиво, 2) при отправки сообщения командой эта команда в моем сообщении боту тоже кликабельна, и этого желательно избежать.

Comment: @CausonQ - Нет, вернее не совсем про диплинки. Диплинк с командой старт позволяет передать параметр, - это да, однако при клике в сообщении появляется сперва кнопка "запустить", нажатие на которую и отправляет команду /start. Это два клика, да и снова команда светится в исходящем сообщении. При использовании кнопок такого не происходит, но их использование сильно лимитировано...

Comment: @Евгений в таком случае, опишите вашу задачу. Не очень понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под `взаимодействием гиперссылками` и `в моменте одного клинка`

Comment: @CausonQ - обновил вопрос для наглядности.

Comment: @Евгений я все равно не очень понимаю для чего это... Ну можно передавать на API  `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/METHOD_NAME`. Но в этом случае, при нажатии на ссылку будет открываться эта страница в браузере

Comment: @CausonQ - для текстовой игры в виде Telegram-бота. Спасибо за вариант, но он не подходит. Вероятно придется пользоваться командами.

Comment: @Евгений а чем инлайн кнопки-то не подходят? Если текстовый квест, так вроде ж вообще ж идеальный вариант: отправлять картинку, текст и кнопки с вариантами действий. И, в зависимости от выбора игрока, можно менять текст в самом сообщении

Comment: @CausonQ - работа с инлайн-кнопками (да и просто кнопками) очень жестко [лимитирована](https://limits.tginfo.me/ru-RU).

Comment: @Евгений и в чем же она для вас ограничена? Всегда всем хватало, но вам почему то нет. Опишите почему

Comment: @MrShandy - 1) Количество кнопок до 100 штук,
2) Markup-данные сообщения например, inline-кнопки до 10 KB. Мой проект предполагает больше кнопок и больший объем данных Markup

Comment: @Евгений стоит задуматься над оптимизацией

Comment: @MrShandy - Этим и занят. Пробовал удалять кнопки после сообщения, но на это нужен отдельный запрос и тогда я быстро упираюсь в другие лимиты (частота запросов к BotAPI и к-во сообщений в сек во все чаты), получая то 400 то 429. Все это обходится таймерами, но значительно замедляет бота даже при незначительной нагрузке. Для понимания это текстовая ММО. Придется использовать команды.

Comment: @MrShandy - В общем сделаю пока команды, а там как попрет. Спасибо за участие.

Comment: @Евгений я одного понять не могу, как можно упереться в лимит 10 кб? Игры текстом я не понимаю, потому что есть mini apps, но видимо кому то интересно. Либо вы делаете что то не так, либо я чего то не понимаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобравшись в документации, сам отвечу на свой вопрос: В настоящий момент **никак**. Только 3 способа, перечисленные в теме вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать текстовую игру используя кнопки. Конфигурация игры пишется в отдельном файле `questions.json` файл должен лежать в корневом каталоге, там же где лежит основной файл `game.js` код ниже. Так же нужен файл оценки викторины `rating.json`.

Файл `game.js`

```
    const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
    const questions = require('./questions.json');//Загружаем данные из json файла
    const rating = require('./rating.json');//Загружаем данные из json файла

    const token = "******************************************";//Ваш токен
    const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {
      polling: true
    });


    function generateButtons(answers) {
      let keyboard = [];
      answers = answers.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);//Перемешивает массив ответов
      answers.forEach((answer, index) => {
        keyboard.push([{text: answer}]);
      });
      return {keyboard};
    }

    function reply(chatId, text, keyboard) { //Отправляет кнопки с вариантами ответа и вопрос
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, text, {
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboard)
      });
    };

    function estimate(chatId, count){//Выбор оценки пройденной викторины
        let diapasones = Object.keys(rating);
        for (let val of diapasones){
            if(count <= Number(val) ){
                return reply(chatId, rating[val].text, removeKeyboard);
            }
        }
        reply(chatId, "Очень плохой результат. Вы вышли за диапазон оценок. Начнём заново?", yes_no);
    }
    function reset(){
        control = null;
        counter_incorrect_answers = 0;
    }
    let removeKeyboard = {remove_keyboard: true};
    let yes_no = {keyboard:[[{text: 'Да'}],[{text: 'Нет'}]]}
    let incorrect = "Не верный ответ. Попробуйте ещё!";

    let control = null;
    let counter_incorrect_answers = 0;


    bot.on('message', function (msg){

      let text = msg.text, chatId = msg.from.id;

      if (text === "/start") {
        reply(chatId, "Поиграем?", yes_no);
      }
      
      if (text === "Нет") {
        return bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Ok");
      }

      if (text === "Да") {
        control = 'question_1';
        reply(chatId, questions[control].question, generateButtons(questions[control].answers));
        text = null;
      }

      if (control && text) {
        
        if (questions[control].end_answer) {//Контроль последнего вопроса, свойство в файле questions.json      
            estimate(chatId, counter_incorrect_answers);//Оценка викторины
            return reset();
        }

        if (text === questions[control].correct_answer) {
            control = questions[control].next_question;
            reply(chatId, questions[control].question, generateButtons(questions[control].answers));
        } else {
          bot.sendMessage(chatId, incorrect);
          counter_incorrect_answers++;
        }    
        text = null;
      }

    });
```

Файл `questions.json`. Свойство `end_answer` есть только у последнего вопроса.

```
{
  "question_1": {
    "question": "Столица России?",
    "correct_answer": "Москва",
    "answers": ["Москва", "Питер", "Владивосток", "Казань"],
    "next_question": "question_2"
  },
  "question_2": {
    "question": "Столица Франции?",
    "correct_answer": "Париж",
    "answers": ["Париж", "Марсель", "Лион", "Ницца"],
    "next_question": "question_3"
  },
  "question_3": {
    "question": "Столица Египта?",
    "correct_answer": "Каир",
    "answers": ["Каир", "Хургада", "Луксор", "Асуан"],
    "end_answer": true
  }
}
```

Файл `rating.json`

```
{
    "3": {
        "text": "Хороший результат!"
    },
    "5": {
        "text": "Не плохо!"
    },
    "10": {
        "text": "Вам нужно подтянуть знания!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо, но это не является ответом на вопрос. Я повторюсь, мне нужно именно дать возможность передавать в сообщениях от бота ссылку, нажатие на которую отправляется сообщение в чат. Поясню так: Я делаю пошаговую многопользовательскую игру, которая подразумевает отправку большого количества запросов на Bot API телеги. При нагрузке я упираюсь в лимиты телеги (По количеству кнопок, по колиеству запросов в сек во все чаты, по объему inline-данных, по количеству ответов в секунду в один чат...)

Comment: А есть еще лимиты VDS, proxy, количеству коннектов к webhook и кто его знает, какие еще вылезут... Потому ищу способ максимально упростить юзабилити игры.

Comment: @Евгений "По количеству кнопок" больше 100 за раз не отправляйте и не упретесь. В каждый чат с пользователем, бот может в минуту кидать сообщение каждые 3 секунды. А как вообще решает вопрос с ограничениями работа "гиперссылками"? Впечатление складывается, что вы не правильно понимаете ограничения. Вряд ли вы доберетесь до ограничений. По VDS и proxy купите больше мощности проблем-то. С webhook тоже вы вряд ли доберетесь до конца лимита.

Comment: Еще раз благодарю, но как я сообщал ранее, я уже на стадии тестирования уперся в лимиты, которые перечислил. И самые первые лимиты, в которые я уперся - это лимит в 30 сообщений в секунду во все чаты и лимит на объем markup-данных (те самые inline-кнопки в том числе) равный 10 кб. И если с первым можно работать, то вот второй хотелось бы обойти. B это при довольно малой нагрузке (равносильной примерно 150 пользователям).

Comment: Возвращаясь к сути вопроса, правильно я понимаю, что мою задачу (про клик на гиперссылку) сейчас никак не решить?

Comment: я только осознал, что в лимит по Markup попадут и гиперссылки... Вероятно придется использовать клавиатуру под поле ввода сообщений, отправляющую текст в чат, а также команды. Все остальное чревато потолком лимитов...